# HAVING 0 = COUNT

Tags: sql, having

```
HAVING 0 = COUNT(1)) AS a
```

What does this mean ?

```
SELECT outr.*
  FROM Orders outr
 WHERE
EXISTS (   SELECT *
                    FROM (   SELECT ol.Orders_ID
                               FROM Orderlines AS ol
                              WHERE Status NOT IN ( 5, 6 )
                              GROUP BY ol.Orders_ID
                             HAVING 0 = COUNT(1)) AS a
                   WHERE outr.Orders_ID = a.Orders_ID)
```

Comment: Can you share the entire query please?

Comment: It means your query will fail...that's not valid SQL

Comment: I will add it to the original question

Comment: I believe your query will return nothing because it is filtered to only pull groups that have a count of 0.

Comment: Its part of a bigger query, for simplicity and security I can only show this much. I was just intrigued to know what the HAVING 0 = count (1) serves. This was an input from a colleague.

Comment: It could also be read `HAVING COUNT(1) = 0` if it makes more sense

Comment: That makes more sense. I still don't see the purpose it serves. Is it looking for all orders that don't have a matching orderline ?

Comment: The `having` would filter out groups similar to how `where` would filter out rows. The count(1) = 0 part will always be false. It's likely someone essentially disabled this script by changing/adding this having clause to prevent anything from returning.

Comment: Thanks. I have removed it from the code. It was of no use to the query as a whole, in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AS a` is an alias for the derived table.  Simplified:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT Orders_ID
      FROM Orderlines
      GROUP BY Order_ID
      HAVING 0 = COUNT(1)
     ) AS a
```

The `HAVING 0 = COUNT(1)` means that the query will only return `Orders_ID` that have a count of 0.  Note that `COUNT(1)` is the same as `COUNT(*)`.

It doesn't make any sense because an `Orders_ID` will never exist AND have a count of 0.

So, the derived table will never return anything, and since it's in an `EXISTS` clause to your outer query, neither will the outer query.